# Quick Way to Bluk Copy Azure Blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have about 40,000 blobs in azure storage, they have been given the wrong file extension. They have been uploaded with the filename `<name>.png` and I need to correct the name to `<name>.jpg`. In the 1st instance I'd like simply copy the originals into the same blob store but with a new file name.

azcopy would normally be my go to for this kind of thing, but it doesn't seem to have the options I need.

How can I bulk copy and rename files in an azure blob store?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Blob Storage doesn't support renaming directly. However, you can work it around by copying the blob to a new blob with modified name (by [StartCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt433229.aspx) method), and removing the original blob (by [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.delete.aspx) method). The copy procedure can be pretty fast if the source and destination is under the same storage account since it's actually a shallow copy.